# Splitting data frame according to (dichotomous) values in a column

Tags: r

I am working with a large data frame, which has 'sex' as one of the columns. It lookssomething like this

```
OriginalDF

SEX X1 X2 X3 X4
0   15 91 12 25
1   12 92 32 35
1   14 94 12 45
0   12 91 42 15
0   11 95 12 25
```

I would like to be able to transform it into two separate dataframes, based on the binary sex variable;

```
DF1

SEX X1 X2 X3 X4
0   15 91 12 25
0   12 91 42 15
0   11 95 12 25

DF2

SEX X1 X2 X3 X4
1   12 92 32 35
1   14 94 12 45
```

How can I accomplish this efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `dplyr` too to accomplish it: `df %>% split(.$sex)`. It will return you a list with both `data.frames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Using data frames
DF1 <- OriginalDF[OriginalDF$SEX == 0, ]
DF2 <- OriginalDF[OriginalDF$SEX == 1, ]

# If it's very large, I recommend you data.table
library(data.table)
OriginalDT <- data.table(OriginalDF)
DT1 <- OriginalDT[SEX == 0]
DT2 <- OriginalDT[SEX == 1]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, I was putting the comma in the wrong place...

Comment: Just added data.table in edit if your data is very large. And actually it's better and easier to use it :-)

Comment: This does not generalize. If you want to split by a factor with n levels (rather than just two) then It is not possible to do it manually as you show in your answer

Comment: Yes I agree it's possible to generalize to n factors, that's not what it's asked. Dichotomous : dividing into 2 branches/factors, right?